# Dictionary value for all keys gets deleted automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**Code**

```
 def fill_dictionary_with_valid_addr_row_data( df ):

        data_list = []
        dictionary = {}
        int_endianness = 0

        for i in df.index:
            addrstr = str(df['Address'][i])

            if (addrstr != 'nan'):

                try:
                    addr = int(addrstr, 16)

                except:
                    print("Address in excel is not in hex format : %s", addrstr)
                    sys.exit()

                width = int(df['Width'][i])
                width = int(width / 8);

                endianess = df['Endianess'][i]
                if (endianess != 'B') and (endianess != 'L'):
                    print("ERROR: Register endianess is not B or L");
                    print("Register : %x, Endianess : %s" % (addr, endianess))
                    sys.exit()

                if endianess == 'B':
                    int_endianness = 1

                data_list.append(addr)
                data_list.append(width)
                data_list.append(int_endianness)

                dictionary[i] = data_list
                print(dictionary)

                data_list.clear()

        print(dictionary)

        return dictionary
```

**Problem**

When i print dictionary inside for loop, Everything is fine. When i print dictionary outside for loop, all the value(lists) are empty.

**Below are the logs**

```
{0: [22216704, 4, 1]}
{0: [22216716, 4, 1], 5: [22216716, 4, 1]}
{0: [22216720, 4, 1], 5: [22216720, 4, 1], 7: [22216720, 4, 1]}
{0: [], 5: [], 38: [], 7: []}
```

I am a beginner python programmer. I tried to search a lot over internet but I have not found any solution.

Any clues?

Comment: because of data_list.clear() which you have written inside the loop.

Comment: Provide a **minimal** example please. Try to reduce your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the indentation of the code above is exactly as in your editor? I don't think that code matches the output.

Comment: @Pushplata You can see that dictionary gets printed correctly everytime inside for loop even if i clear the list every time.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Code is exactly same as i test it. Why do you think code do not match the output?

Comment: Ah, right. Nevermind. I wrapped my head around it. See my answer.

Comment: @JagsVG Yes, because every-time you append value to data_list before printing the dictionary.That's why dictionary always get value inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you do `dictionary[i] = data_list`, you actually assign a reference of the list to the dictionary entry. Consider the following example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> d = {}
>>> d["a"] = l
>>> d["b"] = l
>>> d
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> l.clear()
>>> d
{'a': [], 'b': []}
```

As you can see the change to `l` is reflected in all dictionary values. What you see in your printed output every time is the same list being assigned to one, two or three dictionary entries respectively. Because it's always the same values, it looks as if you added different lists each time, but that's not true.

What you actually want to do is create a new list for every loop iteration:

```
for i in df.index:
    ...

    data_list = []
    data_list.append(addr)
    data_list.append(width)
    data_list.append(int_endianness)
    dictionary[i] = data_list
```

or shorter:

```
dictionary[i] = [addr, width, int_endianness]
```

Using this code `data_list` will contain a new list every iteration, with no connection to the previously defined lists.

Comment: data_list gets clear for every iterations anyway then why does dictionary get printed correctly inside for loop?

Comment: @JagsVG because you are first filling the shared list, printing the dictionary with its references and AFTER that you clear the list. If you print the dictionary before adding items to the list or after clearing the list, you will notice that it changes all dictionary values.